# ¿Cómo relaciono 3 colecciones en mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que tengo una coleción llamada`cursos`, su campo `_id` quiero reacionarlo con el campo `codCurs` de la colección `asignaturas`. Y el campo `codProf` de `asignaturas` quiero relacionarlo con el campo `_id` de una colección llamada `profesores`.
Es decir el fin es obtener, mediante una api, los cursos, con un **array** de las asignaturas y que cada asignatura tenga un array con los datos del profesor. He intentado el siguiente código:

```
courseCtrl.getCourses = async (req, res) => {

    const courses = await Course.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'asignaturas',
                    let: { userid: '$_id' },
                    pipeline: [
                        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$codCurs', '$$userid'] } } },
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                from: 'profesores',
                                let: { uid: "$cofProf" },
                                pipeline: [
                                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$uid"] } } }],
                                as: "profeAsignatura"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: 'asignaturaCurso'
                }
            },
        ]
    )
    res.json(courses);
}
```

El caso es que el primer array si lo hace pero el segundo siempre aparece vacío, da igual el orden en el que los haga, por lo que la relación en sí está bien hecha, ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo, u otra manera de relacionar las 3 colecciones? Gracias

La respuesta esperada es:

```
{
        "_id": "60b3cb56ae5e172974b16c7a",
        .
        .
        .
        "nombre": "DAM 2",
        "createdAt": "2021-05-30T17:28:54.414Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-05-30T18:11:09.006Z",
        "asignaturaCurso": [
            {
                "_id": "60b3d476b7815135c0c16c57",
                "nameSubj": "Acceso a Datos",
                "codProf": "60b3d0faae5e172974b16cb0",
                "codCurs": "60b3cb56ae5e172974b16c7a",
                "createdAt": "2021-05-30T18:07:50.610Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-05-30T18:07:50.610Z",
                "profeAsignatura": [

                                   Y aqui los datos del profesor correspondiente 
                                   a la asignatura

                 ]
            }

        ]
}
```

Comment: por favor visualiza los valores de tus colecciones.

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo de lo que intentas recibir de dicha consulta ?

Comment: Haz clic en [edit] y agrega los detalles a la pregunta. Aquí en los comentarios no debes agregar código, ya que de por sí es limitado el espacio y no se ve bien lo que tratas de lograr. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
const getData = async () => {
    const courses = await CursosModel.aggregate([
        {
        $lookup: {
            from: "asignaturas",
            let: { codCourse: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$$codCourse", "$course"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "profesores",
                        localField: "teacher",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: 'profe'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$profe"
                }
            ],
            as: 'data'
        }
    }
    ])
    console.log(JSON.stringify(courses))
}
```

Comment: Un poco de texto aclarando la respuesta sería de mucha ayuda.